# In swift, how to generate a multidimensional array?

Tags: arrays, swift, probability

I have an array :

```swift
let myArray : [Int] = [1, 1, 1]
```

3 numbers are an example. In the reality, it will be different each time.
And I have variables of minimum and maximum

```
let valueMin = 1
let valueMax = 500
```

I need to generate a FinalArray that will contain all the possible values ​​between min and max of each number of my initial array.

Here is an example:

for the beginning we have the first possibility and it's possibility001: [1, 1, 1]

I add this value to my FinalArray

```
var finalArray : [[Int]] = []

finalArray.append(possibility001)
```

The second value:
possibility002: [1, 1, 2]

```
finalArray.append(possibility002)
```

possibility003: [1, 1, 3]

at one point, we will have
possibility 14.944.020: [230, 182, 357]

etc until possibilityFinal: [500, 500, 500]

```
finalArray.append(possibilityFinal)
```

How could I make multi dimensional loop to create it?

Comment: I don't understand. How is 4 a possible sum of `[1, 1, 1]`?

Comment: This is indeed hard to understand. How do the values in `myArray` come into play? How and where is there a multidimensional array involved? How is a "dictionary of probabilities" the same as an array where only sums are appended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do that using a recursive logic in a function:

```
func possibleSums(min: Int, max: Int, length: Int) -> [Int] {
    guard length > 0 else { return [] }

    var sums = [Int]()
    for i in min...max {
        if length == 1 {
            sums.append(i)
        } else {
            let subSums = possibleSums(min: min, max: max, length: length - 1).map { $0 + i }
            sums.append(contentsOf: subSums)
        }
    }
    return sums
}
```

This will return an array with all possible sums including duplicate ones. But it will need to run like forever in your case:

```
let sums = possibleSums(min: 1, max: 500, length: myArray.count)
```

If you want to ditch the duplicate sum values, you can do something like this:

```
func possibleSums(min: Int, max: Int, length: Int) -> [Int] {
    guard length > 0 else { return [] }

    var sums = [Int]()
    for i in min...max {
        if length == 1 {
            sums.append(i)
        } else {
            let subSums = possibleSums(min: i, max: max, length: length - 1).map { $0 + i }
            sums.append(contentsOf: subSums)
        }
    }
    return sums
}
```

This will also take a long time to finish.

**Update**: To create a function that returns all the possible arrays without summing the numbers in each one, you can do something like this:

```
func possibleArrays(min: Int, max: Int, length: Int) -> [[Int]] {
    guard length > 0 else { return [] }

    var arrays = [[Int]]()
    for i in min...max {
        if length == 1 {
            arrays.append([i])
        } else {
            let subArrays: [[Int]] = possibleArrays(min: min, max: max, length: length - 1).map {
                var array = $0
                array.insert(i, at: 0)
                return array
            }
            arrays.append(contentsOf: subArrays)
        }
    }
    return arrays
}
```

Comment: are you using a function inside itself ? you do that to iterate in the array to create the variations. it avoids creating the nested manually

Comment: @Monica yes, exactly.

Comment: @Monica I updated my answer. You may also have to update your question to indicate your actual problem.